# export ubuntu system with all programs as iso file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iso

I working on hotspot system using ubuntu and every things go fine . now I want to sell my system , but this system need many other programs and configuration , so I want to export my ubuntu machine with all config and programs to iso file and  user will install this system , ie (I will send iso file to user and he will install it like any other ubuntu system )
how can I do that ?

Comment: That's not the right way to go about it; for example, all the passwords and other unique identifiers would have well-known default values. Instead, bundle up the configuration files etc that make it custom.

Comment: thank you for your reply but what you suggest for me , my system is php system so user must install php, mysql, and enable many extension into it , I suppose that the user does not know more about this things

Comment: how can I make my system install php , mysql, enable extension automatically . we know that linux and ubuntu need permission for every things so my system can not be able to install these programs automatically

Comment: Creating custom Ubuntu isos [is well documented](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization). Follow the instructions, feel free to ask specific questions if you encounter them.

Comment: I'd recommend creating .deb packages for your application and setting up a  repository for it. This will make it a lot easier to maintain your software in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Although I would recommend building a kickstart file for the particular system configs you need, if you want an exact replica of your system as an .iso, [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) is a good tool to try.

Comment: how can I make Kickstart file?

Comment: This is worth a read and should point you in the right direction: [kickstart](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/ch04s06.html). If you have any specific questions, I can try my best to help!